# Freeze control while vertical scrolling

Tags: wpf, xaml, scroll, scrollviewer

I have some group of controls inside ScrollViewer. I need one of this controls to freeze while vertical scrolling. How do I do this?

Comment: snurre, I mean not scroll together with the other controls. For example in DataGrid column headers don't move while vertical scrolling.

Comment: You should move the control out of the ScrollViewer and only keep items that actually need to scroll inside it.

Comment: The control need to scroll horizontally but don't need to scroll vertically. Again the same as column headers in DataGrid.

Comment: Post your XAML and identify control you need to freeze.

Answer (score 0):

By some creative use of ListView, you can achieve the desired effect. You might also have to tweak the ListView template some to avoid certain ListView-specific behaviours.

```
    <ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!-- Header/Frozen content goes here -->
                            <!-- Using Border as example -->
                            <Border Width="1000" Height="40">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Lime"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Black"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <!-- Other content goes here -->
                                <!-- Using Border as example -->
                                <Border Width="1000" Height="1000">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush>
                                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="White"/>
                                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Black"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListViewItem.Style>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work. Vertical scrollbar is never visible. Even if it were work to access vertical scrollbar one should first scroll horizontally to the right. It is inappropriate for me.